# What is the ratio between 100 and 0? 100? undefined?

Tags: percentages, ratio

As the title of the topic says, what is the ratio between 100 and 0? In this case, 100 and 0 represent 100% and 0%. A friend of mine says that it is equal to 100 because there is no other case in which it can be equal to 100, and in that case it would mean that for each element in set A there is no element in set B. I tend to believe that it is undefined, because there is a case in which the ratio is almost equal to 100, which is the ratio between 99,01% and 0,99%. Could this issue be seen as a matter of interpretation of the meaning of the ratio, or is there something that we have not considered?

Comment: I agree that there may be multiple ways of making sense of this kind of thing, particularly depending upon what the numbers represent (percentages of what? elements of what sets?), but I agree that the term "ratio" is not the best route to understanding this. It may be that when rephrased in other language, you and your friend are both speaking correctly about different things.

Comment: The ratio of 100 to 1 is 100 (or 10,000%). The ratio of 100 to 0 is undefined. The ratio of A to B is C if A/B=C.

Comment: The real question is not so much "what is the ratio", but what is the underlying reality which you are trying to make sense of. In the integers or real numbers we can't divide by zero - it isn't an operation which gives a value. If that doesn't make sense in your concrete context then you need a different model. (The idea of a limit helps to manage undefined infinities so they cause as little problem as possible)

Comment: As far as I know, it is undefined.

Comment: It is undefined, and the reasoning has nothing to do with the ratio being equal to or close to $100$; in fact, you can make the ratio of $x$ to $100-x$ just about whatever you like by choosing the right value of $x$. If you want a ratio of $r$, then solve $\frac{x}{100-x}=r$. If you draw the graph $y = \frac{x}{100-x}$, you'll see that it "explodes" as $x$ approaches $100$.

Comment: @MarkBennet well, we are talking about male and female in different schools, so the question is refered to ratio between female and male and how it varies across different schools. In the case of the question, I think that it doesn't make sense to talk about the ratio of a given school if there is no male but only female, but I'm not 100% percent sure, hence the question :)

Comment: Well, dividing by zero is pretty much nonsense in that case. If you are looking for gender balance statistics the percentage of female or the percentage of male is normalised to take account of the different size of the schools being compared. There will be differences in small schools (with five students you can't have half male and half female). So division by zero seems to me to reflect a poor choice of indicator.